# Converting ASCII codes that are in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, ascii

Currently, with an api, they're giving me back a string with the ASCII code such as

```
&#39;
```

in it. I was wondering if there was a simple way in Ruby to convert all these different codes to their respective symbol without having to do a manual gsub for each one.

Comment: show some examples,you used.

Comment: I edited my question to properly show the ascii code it was generating

Comment: `&#39;` what you want from this?

Comment: Well that should return an apostrophe. If you were to put that in a webpage the browser would render it properly but in the case I am using it for, it's not gonna be rendered as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require "cgi"
CGI.unescape_html "&#39;"
# => "'"
```